# GTM having two clicks occurance in preview mode , but i did one click only

Tags: google-tag-manager

Does anyone who has epxerienced :

GTM having two clicks occurance in preview mode , but i did one click only in the website, how come it will turn out two gtm.clicks events ,but the event id is different .

does anyone know the reason? how come it will trigger two gtm.click event with different id

Comment: do they have the same click element variable?

Comment: what do you mean by click element variable, it is generated by GTM , event name is gtm.click , for gtm.uniqueEventId , the value is different.

Comment: Go to GTM preview, do the click, select one of the two occured events on the left, go to variables, find the click element variable, make a screenshot. Now go to the other event, find the click element var and compare it to the screenshoted one. Don't bother comparing the whole thing, only the ending of it or like two last lines.

Comment: i checked click element, the click element value between the two , is different. so do you know what triggered , the two elements in on click?

Comment: Yeah, some click bubbling propagation logic. It's fine. Since the selectors are different, all you need to do is to pick one and use it. Your current selector selects both elements, seemingly.

Comment: i think once click event capture the "span"element , another capture "input"element ,just the parent element of "span" , how can i stop this kinds of propagation logic ?  it is the logic of website ?of something with GTM itself?

Comment: GTM has no relation to it. it would be a separate question. Just change your click listener to either listen to input or the span. I imagine you have a broad selector there, capturing both at the moment.